# Buffer an online streaming audio to a file in the sdcard and then play, say from a link(http://81.19.85.204:80/club128.mp3)

Tags: android

I'm developing an application which can buffer online streaming radio to a file 
say, `File downloadingMediaFile = new File("//mnt/sdcard/downloadingMedia.p3");`

And then play using `android's` `MediaPlayer` class. Is it feasible such a streaming? If so, suggest me an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tutorial helped me in a similar situation http://blog.infidian.com/2008/04/04/tutorial-custom-media-streaming-for-androids-mediaplayer/